How to understand the last step of the proof of this inequality?
Let $a$, $b$, $x$, $y$, $z$ real numbers greater or equal than $1$. Then
$$(\log x+\log z)^{\frac{1}{a}}(\log y+\log z)^{\frac{1}{b}}\leq ({\log z})^{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}$$
Is this inequality true? If yes, how to prove it? As others pointer out, the above inequality is false.
The reason I'm writing this question it's because in a paper that I'm reading the authors are using this inequality and I wish to check if it's true.
Ok, since this inequality isn't true, there must be another way to understand the proof, I will upload the proof, I was able to understand almost every step, what I don't understand is the last inequality in the proof. Namely
$$s(\log t_s+\log s)^{\frac{1}{b}}(\log r_s+\log s)^{\frac{1}{a}}\leq s({\log s})^{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}$$
For this theorem, please consider $a \neq b$:


@Victor What's the source of it?

It's written in a paper called " Non-variational elliptic systems in dimension two: a priori bounds and existence of positive solutions by Djairo G. de Figueiredo, João Marcos do Ó and Bernhard Ruf."

Thanks. I think there seems also mistake in the proof. Let $a=2, b=3, s = 6/5$. After setting partial derivatives to zero, they get two equations. However, the two equations do not have solutions on $r \ge 1, t\ge 1$, but have solutions on $r, t \in (0, 1)$. Then the two statements followed seem not true.

@RiverLi Perhaps the idea that if the stationary point isn't $r,t\ge1$ then the minimum is on the boundary, i.e. $r=t=1$? Then the inequality becomes $s\le 2e + s(\log s)^{1/a+1/b}$ which is true considering the cases $s\le e$ and $s>e$. The last line of the proof needs more consideration.

@Ramashalanka Perhaps. But I think that the description of the proof is not nice.

Yes, the construction of $r_s$ and $t_s$ is not sound for me also... I hope this proposition is somehow true, because they prove a nice Theorem afterwards using this inequality.

If $\log$ is the natural logarithm $\ln$, check this example:
$$a = 1, b = 9/8, t = 8, r = 6, s = 200, $$
$$\mathrm{e}^{t^a} + \mathrm{e}^{r^b}
+ s(\ln s)^{1/a + 1/b} - rst
= \mathrm{e}^{8} + \mathrm{e}^{6^{9/8}}
+ 200(\ln 200)^{17/9} - 9600 = -134.813.$$

Let $a=b=z=1$ and $x=y=c$ where $c$ is the base of your logarithm, then the inequality says
$$(1+0)^{1/1}(1+0)^{1/1}\le(0)^{1/1+1/1}\implies 1\le0$$
